# Storing dynamic input values in Meteor JS form

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I currently have a form that stores data to the database on submit. I now have the additional code:

```
'click .addmore': function(event){
      $('.addmore').before('<label>Other Appearance: </label><input class="additionalAppearances" type="text"/>')
}
```

This adds additional fields. How can I store **these** additional values to the Database?

BTW: Here's how I'm storing my values already. I want to store the additional values to this:

```
  var publisherVar = event.target.publisher.value.toLowerCase().replace(' ','');
  var superheroVar = event.target.superhero.value;
  var firstAppearance = event.target.appearance.value;
  var coverImage = event.target.coverImage.value;
  var imgDescript = event.target.imgDescript.value;
  ComicsList.insert({
    publisher: publisherVar,
    superhero: superheroVar,
    appearance: firstAppearance,
    coverImage: coverImage,
    imgDescript: imgDescript
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did you find a solution? I am having similar issue and would love to her how did you fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the insert to an update.

```
  ComicsList.update({_id:this._id}{$set{publisher: publisherVar,
superhero: superheroVar,
appearance: firstAppearance,
coverImage: coverImage,
imgDescript: imgDescript
}});
```

`this._id,` refers to the current document, if you have the submit inside an `{{#each}}`, it will work

Comment: I wound up going to different way due to the purpose of the app. This did work for a different part of my project, though.